# JQuery fire event for element's child

Tags: jquery, events, siblings

I create jquery custom function.

I want fire event on selector sibling or child like this:

```
$.fn.CustomFunction = function() {
    $(this).siblings("div").click(function(){
        alert();
    });

    // OR

    $(this + " > div").click(function(){
        alert();
    });
};
```

But it not work.

How i do this work?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$.fn.CustomFunction = function() {
    $(this).on('click', 'div', function(){
        alert();
    });
);
```

It binds a click event on the selector `div` inside `this`.
More info: http://api.jquery.com/on/